# Handling unclosed HTML tags

Tags: html, tags

When certain page is loaded I retrieve some information from a legacy database to populate certain tabs.
One of those tabs is 'Related Videos'. The information for Related
Videos in the database is stored as a string which contain the url for the video enclosed in some tags
(additional classes). Now, the problem is the following, in the maintenance there was a text area
where the user used to place the code for related videos, but this text area allowed only 512 characters (due to poor design)
 hence some information wasn't save in the database correctly, more specifically some closing tags, so I ended up with
things like this:

```
<div class="video">
    <a href="//www.youtube.com/v/asasdsdqqwq&autoplay=1" youtubeid="asasdasdas" class="video-link"> 
    <img src="http://i.aasda.com/vi/adsdadsasd/default.jpg" alt="asdasdadasd" width="128" height="72">
    </a>
    <div class="paly">
        <a id="vxcxcvc" class="video-link" youtubeid="vxvxvx" href="//www.youtube.com/v/xcxcvxc">
        MY VIDEO
        </a>
    </div><!--<span> (2:21)</span
```

So, when I retrieve the information from the DB to my template there are some problems because there are open
tags that are supposed to be closed.

The text area size was fixed as well as the database field, but I need to deal with the existing
code from the database, I cannot go through every record and fix those with unclosed tags because
there are thousands of records.

Any recommendation?

Comment: If it is always the same, read the fragment and add `--></div>` to it or replace `</span` with `</span--></div>`

Comment: It's not always the same @mplungjan